# Why does this program run so slow in processing.exe?

Tags: windows-7, processing

Why does this program run so slow in processing.exe?

On a 3GHz Windows 7 machine with Intel graphics, the program below shows only about 1fps in processing.exe, but is full speed in sketchpad http://studio.sketchpad.cc/sp/pad/view/5nIdnL3RQ8/rev.0 in Chrome.

```java
int amount = 30;
int[] x = new int[amount];
int[] y = new int[amount];
int[] z = new int[amount];

void setup() {
  size(500, 400, P3D);
  background(0);
  noFill();
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(1);
  for(int i = 0; i<amount; i++) {
    x[i] = int(random(-150, 150));
    y[i] = int(random(-150, 150));
    z[i] = int(random(-150, 150));
  }
}
void draw() {
  background(0);

  translate(width/2, height/2);

  rotateY(sin(frameCount/100)*1);

  for(int i = 0; i<amount; i++) {
    point(x[i], y[i], z[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is running at 60 fps. You can confirm this by adding this right after your call to `background()`:

```java
text(frameRate, 25, 25);
```

That will show you the current frame rate every frame, and you'll see that it's constantly updating.

Your problem is this line:

```java
rotateY(sin(frameCount/100)*1);
```

Note that both `frameCount` and `100` are `int` values. They don't have a decimal place, and any operation involving them just drops the decimal place anyway. So:

```java
0/100 = 0
25/100 = 0
99/100 = 0
100/100 = 1
125/100 = 1
```

So, what's happening is that the value of `frameCount/100` only changes every `100` frames. So the value you get back from the `sin()` function only changes every `100` frames. That's why it looks like you're only getting 1 fps.

You can confirm this by adding a little print statement just before that line:

```java
println("frameCount/100=" + (frameCount/100));
println("sin: " + sin(frameCount/100));
```

The solution to that is to use a `float` value instead. These values do have a decimal part, and any operation involving them has a decimal part as well. To do this, just add a decimal part to your `100` to make it `100.0`. Processing will know you want that to be a `float` value, and now your results will be `floats` as well:

```java
0/100.0 = 0.0
25/100.0 = 0.25
99/100.0 = 0.99
100/100.0 = 1.0
125/100.0 = 1.25
```

So you just need to change that line to this:

```java
rotateY(sin(frameCount/100.0));
```